# How to add Next/Previous button/Controll in MPMediaPlayerController in xcode?

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmediaplayercontroller

I have added `MPMediaPlayerController` in my View but it only shows **Play** and **Pause** Button.

The control **does not show Next/Previous** button.

How to **add Next/Previous** control in  `MPmediaPlayerController` ?

Comment: do you mean MPMoviePlayerController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[mp setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen]; // mp is an instance of MPMoviePlayerController
```

Comment: Thanks Harsh.... but i used above code..... but still not working .... please check below code.... if any error then let me know....       UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];                                                        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:selectedsong ofType:@"mp3"];
 moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]]; 
 moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
 [moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];